# Is there any drawback for having one large (e.g. 512 GB) hard drive partition for Windows 10 instead of having two smaller ones?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, partitioning, ssd, windows-10

I just got a new laptop ( Asus ) with one 512 ePCI SSD harddrive.

From the factory, the system comes with two partitions:

1. the one with windows on it, size ~190GB
2. a second one called "data", size ~270GB

With my last laptop I also had 2 harddisks, but when the C drive filled up, it was very annoying: I still had plenty of space on the second HD, but some things just needed to be on the C drive.

Here's my question:
Are there any drawbacks for having a very large ( 500 GB ish) sized partition? I'm just doing the upgrade to Windows 10, so that's going to be the OS of the laptop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is purely personal choice. If the partition fills up and you need to install or update software then you may need to resize the partition. Be careful, however, as resizing a partition can lead to data loss.

For convenience it is much easier to use a single partition spanning the entire disk - so you don't have to worry about moving/resizing partitions, however, you don't have the separation between an OS partition and a separate "data" partition - in case you have to re-install your OS, for example. With two partitions you can keep your data on one partition, re-install the OS that's on the other partition and your personal data will be fine.

Another thing to watch for is partitions still reside on the same physical disk (if you only have one disk, that is) so you don't have any protection from disk failure.

If "I" were doing it I'd use one large partition (the full disk) and make sure I've got a regular backup of my most important files (cloud storage, USB, NAS etc.) - but that's an opinion based answer so you must make a decision that works for you.

Comment: Thanks! Follow up comment, might help others too: Can I repartition with data being on the disks? Or will repartitioning require me to move the data somewhere else?

Comment: If y you have data on the second ("data") partition you will need to back this up as you'll delete the data partition to extend the OS partition, which will delete all data on that partition. You could move it all to the OS partition if you have space. This will save a bit of time and if you haven't got a backup device.

Comment: Just did this. One hint: The "Extend partition" will be greyed out if there's another partition behind the system partition, even if there is available "space" on the disk. In order to extend the system partition, there needs to be unpartitioned space right behind the system partition.

Comment: Yes, the free space (from Disk Management view) must be to the RIGHT of the partition you want to extend. A default install of Windows will do this so they don't expect to see it any different... The traditional partition arrangement: `[system reserved][Windows][any other...]`

Answer (score 1):

On Windows this is a minor point, but on e.g. a Linux system, putting your personal data (home folder) in a separate partition has the advantage, that installing another (Linux) operating system (OS) on the OS Partition does not require to copy your personal data to the new installation.

On Windows, in theory this is also possible, but there is minor need to install other operating systems, and when re-installing windows you typically don't want to keep an old partion, where there could be viruses in some files (main reason for reinstalling Windows).

My personal advice: When you use multiple OS or change them frequently, separate your personal data from the OS on separate partitions, otherwise make a single large partition to benefit from the flexibility (e.g. Data is full, OS almost empty)